# Filebeat message ordering during aggressive log rotation

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

We log a ton of data in the following format:

```
{"record_id": "123abc", "version": 1, "status": "old_status", ...}
{"record_id": "123abc", "version": 2, "status": "new_status", ...}
```

We then use Filebeat to ship these logs off the server into a Kafka cluster. With smaller volumes of log data, this worked well. The messages appeared in Kafka in the same order that they were logged to the log file.

Now that we have reached a log volume that requires us to aggressively rotate the logs, we are seeing messages come through Kafka out of order. I think what is happening is Filebeat creates a new harvester when the log file is rotated. Something like this:

**Before:**

```
Filebeat harvester 1 -> log
```

**After:**

```
Filebeat harvester 2 -> log
Filebeat harvester 1 -> log.rotate
```

With 2 harvesters, I think files are getting sent from both files to Kafka simultaneously, which leads to out of order messages in Kafka. **Note:** I verified that messages are sent to the correct partitions in Kafka, so the message ordering issue is not due to logs being sent to separate partitions.

My questions are:

1. What are the message ordering guarantees in Filebeat, and how are they impacted by log rotation?
2. Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Filebeat should ignore rotated files because they would already have been consumed

Comment: we've noticed lag with our Filebeat instance, so there are times when the rotated file has not been entirely processed